# Physic world bounds

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm perigrinating with cocos2d **version 3** for iOS, by following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/61391/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-3-0-tutorial).

It's really basic. In the one `CCScene` of the app, we create a world :

```
_physicsWorld = [CCPhysicsNode node];
_physicsWorld.gravity = ccp(0,-100);
_physicsWorld.debugDraw = YES;
[self addChild:_physicsWorld];
```

And then add a protagonist sprite with body.

```
_protagonist = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"player.png"];
_protagonist.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2, self.contentSize.height/2);
_protagonist.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, _protagonist.contentSize} cornerRadius:0];
[_physicsWorld addChild:_protagonist];
```

Now, here's my problem. The protagonist sprite falls because there's a {0;-100} gravity vector. But, it never stops. So **it gets out of the screen and to never be seen again.**

*This is normal, I get it.*

So I'm trying to create a world bounding box, with 4 `CCPhysicNode`. For instance, and the most important one atm, the bottom line to stop the fall of the protagonist :

```
CCPhysicsNode* bottom = [CCPhysicsNode node];
bottom.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentSize.width, 20);
bottom.position = ccp(0, self.contentSize.height);
bottom.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, bottom.contentSize} cornerRadius:0];
[_physicsWorld addChild:bottom];
```

As I understand the cocos2d's chipmunk integration, this should :

- create a cocos2d physic node at coordinates (0,1136) and frame of size (320,20)
- attach a chipmunk body with a shape the size of the physics node (320,20)
- detect collision with the protagonist (or should it ? should it be in the same `collisionGroup` ?)

**What happens on the screen : nothing**. Yup, with `debugDraw=true`, nothing is drawn. The protagonist sprite keeps falling, just like Gandalf, but to its doom instead, to the abyss of the `y` axis infinity (and beyond!).

To rephrase, adding the `bottom CCPhysicsNode`doesn't change a thing.

Help!

Many thanks in return.

Comment: You're periwhat with? Oh, you meant 'experiminting with'. :)  I don't know the new CCPhysicsNode and chipmunk all too well, but you should make a static body (edge, chain, ...), not a dynamic one. The dynamic body will fall, too.

Comment: Oh yup that's right! a static thingy, is what I need. I don't know how to do that with the new API though. Going to look around. Btw : [pérégrination](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A9r%C3%A9grination)

Comment: As "LearnCocos2D" said before, you need to make a static body and add it to the main physicsNode. A physicsNode is only used to contain physic bodies, it can't be visible. So try to make a sprite with static physic body attached to it, and then add it to the same physicsNode as the protagonist

Answer (score 0):

CCPhysicsNode is just a world container that holds all physics objects in your game. Do not create a new one for each physics object. Instead create a CCNode and attach its physics body. Then add your new CCNode to the CCPhysicsNode. In other word, your code looks okay, except for the first line which should be:

```
CCNode* bottom= [CCNode node];
```